# How can configure Rekorbox so that it records the computed BPM in the MP3 ID3's BPM field?

Tags: mp3

Rekorbox computes the BPM of an MP3 while analyzing it. How can I configure Rekorbox so that it records the computed BPM in the MP3 ID3's BPM field?

Comment: It's been suggested that this be moved to the Sound Design SE site.  I agree.  Would you like this migrated?

Comment: Do yo want to do the same for [Program to merge two MP3s](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2393/903)?

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with Sound Design.

Comment: @BrendanRehill Off-topicness is no reason to downvote. Flags are here for that purpose. I'm cool with migrating it back if SD is no place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently. Rekordbox only saves Key. You would have to export the value and apply it externally with an ID3 bulk editor or in command line with a script.